# Database corruption

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, localdb

I am planning to use `localdb` for next project and thinking of making rotating backup of database (it will be detached normally and only attached when software is running). And I was thinking how to do automatic restore from backup. This required me to know if database is corrupted. And I can't find anything about this subject.

My guess, peoples don't care on that level about database integrity. Backup and maintenance is a job for IT, there are dozens of tools for SQL Express.

My database will be local on PC and not big. I want to make it very simple:

- detect if database is corrupt (**how?**)
- offer user an option to restore database from most recent backup (this is easy)

P.S.: perhaps I don't know something about  sql express, localdb, linq-to-sql. This is why question is very generic.

---

After getting answer I'll go with simple options:

- if database can't be opened **and file exists** - database is corrupted, offer restore (not exists - create empty database and do initial setup);
- provide following options (if user noticed something unusual or get errors during update, etc.): to check database `DBCC CHECKDB (0, REPAIR_REBUILD)` (could be good to try first) or to restore.

Automatic detection seems costly. Rather keep weekly/montly backup for manual restoration (if that would be really necessary for old data) and create mdf-file backup every run to minimize loss to 1 day maximum (which in my case is totally fine for an abnormal situation like database corruption).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am planning to use localdb for next project a

You mean you plan to run a database that is explicitly not made for running in production on production?

> And I was thinking how to do automatic restore from backup. This required me to know if 
>   database is corrupted. And I can't find anything about this subject.

Read SQL documentation. Backusp, restores are all doe using standard SQL Commands. Totally easy to do that.

> I want to make it very simple:
>   detect if database is corrupt (how?)

DBC Checkdb command. Can take a lot of time, though, depending on the database.

> perhaps I don't know something about sql express, localdb, linq-to-sql.

This can be solved by reading the documentation. I would for example never use localdb on anything production.

Read the documentation? It starts with the first line:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB is an execution mode of SQL Server Express 
>   targeted to program developers.

Comment: *Not made for running in production on production*. It will be a local PC software and I need to store some data, so using database is a good idea (was using mdb before), my colleague is using `localdb`, care to explain to us what we are doing wrong. Thanks for [`DBCC CHECKDB`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx), it sounds like an answer to me! Have to test it first though.

Comment: Well, that is prodeuction and I would use - express at least. SOmething sensible.